# Change line colors of technical indicators made by R quantmod TTR?

Tags: r, quantmod

I tried to plot with chartSeries in the R package quantmod, and add SMI lines using the addSMI() method. SMI generates two lines - the solid line is visible while the dotted line is not. Can anybody propose a way to change the color of the dotted line so that it is more noticeable? Here are the codes. I also attached an image generated.

```
library(quantmod)

x<-getSymbols("IBM", src='yahoo', from="2014-11-20", to="2015-05-20", auto.assign=FALSE)
chartSeries(x, name=paste(stockFirmName,"(",stock,")"), line.type = "l", 
        TA=c(addSMI()), theme = chartTheme("white", up.col='red',dn.col="blue"), major.ticks="months", color.vol=FALSE, multi.col = FALSE) 

title(main="", cex.main=2.5, font.main=4, col.main="gold", 
      sub="", cex.sub=1.5, font.sub=4, col.sub="blue", 
      xlab="", ylab="",col.lab="blue", cex.lab=1)
```

See below for the two lines in the bottom SMI chart.

![image]

Edits: Robert's method made it work. Here is latest code and chart.

```
library(quantmod)

x<-getSymbols("IBM", src='yahoo', from="2014-11-20", to="2015-05-20", auto.assign=FALSE)
chartSeries(x, name=paste("IBM"), line.type = "l", 
        TA=NULL, 
        theme = chartTheme("white", up.col='red',dn.col="blue"), 
              major.ticks="months", color.vol=FALSE, multi.col = FALSE) 

addTA(SMI(HLC(x)),col=2:3)

title(main="", cex.main=2.5, font.main=4, col.main="gold", 
  sub="", cex.sub=1.5, font.sub=4, col.sub="blue", 
  xlab="", ylab="",col.lab="blue", cex.lab=1)
```

The chart is as follows.
[image]

The question now is: the chart can be generated by running line by line. If I "source" the source codes in a batch mode, The SMI subchart does not show up at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about which line is which in the picture and what you mean by "more noticeable"?

Comment: See the two lines in new edits

Comment: Wrap it in a call to `plot()`.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. That is it. Just need to change the addTA line as: `plotaddTA(SMI(HLC(x)),col=2:3))`. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
chartSeries(x, name=paste(stockFirmName,"(",stock,")"), line.type = "l", 
            TA=NULL, theme = chartTheme("white", up.col='green',dn.col='red'), major.ticks="months", color.vol=FALSE) 

addTA(SMI(HLC(x)),col=2:3)
```

Comment: Thanks, Roberts. Almost there. Another question, see the edits.