# Quantmod Oscillators

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

Utilizing the chartSeries function in the quantmod package, I want to modify the RSI oscillator.  Given an xts object containing OHLC price data, here is the call that I am using:

```
chartSeries(plot_report[, 1:4],
        name        = substr(ticker, 1, nchar(ticker) - 4),
        theme       = chartTheme('white.mono', grid.col = NA),
        TA          = c(addRSI(n = 14, maType = "SMA")),
        type        = "line",
        bar.type    = 'ohlc',
        major.ticks = 'months',
        show.grid   = FALSE,
        log.scale   = TRUE)
```

Generating this chart:
[image]

I have four questions:

1. How can I change the default color of blue to something else? I have tried: c(addRSI(n = 14, maType = "SMA", col = "black")). However, I get the "unused argument" error.
2. Can I draw horizontal lines in the oscillator panel? Traditional RSI's have a horizontal red line at a y-axis value of 70 and a horizontal green line at a y-axis value of 30 to indicate overbought/oversold levels.
3. Is it possible to plot another calculation as an oscillator line below the chart? I have some proprietary oscillators that I want to visualize instead of the RSI or any of the indicators in the TTR package.
4. How can I get involved in improving the quantmod charting functionality; is this project being actively maintained?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381639/change-line-colors-of-technical-indicators-made-by-r-quantmod-ttr) can help to change the color (your first question). But, Generally it is better to not ask many questions in the same question.

Comment: wow! thank you @agstudy, i will refrain from asking too many questions in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You can't. You would need to add `...` to the arguments for `addRSI` and modify the body of the function to use `...` appropriately. A work-around is to calculate `RSI` manually, then call `addTA` as done in the answer to [Change line colors of technical indicators made by R quantmod TTR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30381639/271616).
2. Use `addLines`:

`getSymbols("SPY"); chartSeries(SPY, TA="addRSI();addLines(h=c(30,70), on=2)")`

3. Use `addTA` with the object containing your proprietary data.
4. See [quantmod's GitHub page](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod). Yes, it's actively maintained. The last update was pushed to CRAN a couple months ago.